# C#, difficulties interpreting how to use API wrapper

Tags: c#, api

I'm working with an API wrapper for the first time and I'm not doing too hot.

I am not certain where it's going wrong so I'll keep it short but let me know if it's not enough code to determine what the problem is.

From the documentation:

```
public async Task<OrderBookResponse> GetOrderBook(string symbol, bool useCache = false, int limit = 100)
{
    Guard.AgainstNull(symbol);
    if (limit > 100)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("When requesting the order book, you can't request more than 100 at a time.", nameof(limit));
    }
    return await _apiProcessor.ProcessGetRequest<OrderBookResponse>(Endpoints.MarketData.OrderBook(symbol, limit, useCache));
}
```

This is from an example program:

```
var orderBook = await client.GetOrderBook("ETHBTC", true);
```

And finally my own code and problem:

```
public async void fetchPrice()
{
    using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var trades = await client.GetOrderBook("BTCUSDT", false, 50);
            Console.WriteLine(trades);
            {more code}
        }
    }
}
```

`Console.WriteLine` says this instead of the fetched data

> "BinanceExchange.API.Models.Response.OrderBookResponse".

Thanks!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` internally tries to convert to a string whatever you pass as parameter. For objects, it calls the `.ToString()` method of such object. If you need a specific property or value of `trades`, you need to pass that to the `WriteLine` method (e.g. `Console.WriteLine(trades.BookName)`)

Comment: What should 'bookname' be then? I figured it should be trades.symbol but that does not work. trades.toString also returns the same thing.

Comment: Hi JDoe, `trades.toString` returns the class full name because its the default behavior inherited from `object` class. you will need to write (overwrite) one by yourself to have something else printed (add `ToString` method on `OrderBookResponse`).

Comment: @J.Doe that depends; what's the structure of `trades`? What properties or methods does it have?